# Parallel processing of function with different arguments

Tags: python, parallel-processing

So I just wanted to try out some parallelization to speed up my script, but everything I find about it doesn't really help me.

I've got an optimization algorithm running and in every itereation there are several evaluations of different parameters necessary. Each of those evaluations is a simulation which takes like 10 minutes.

```
while(True):
    f_xn = runSim(xn[0],xn[1],25,na)
    f_xb = runSim(xb[0],xb[1],25,na)
    if f_xn < e:
        break
```

So is there a way i can make those two function calls run at the same time and then let the process continue with the values `f_xn` and `f_xb` once they are both finished?

Definition of runSim(). Some lines are missing here, but those are just changing some values in a text file.

```
def runSim(n):
    if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
        tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
        sys.path.append(tools)
    else:   
         sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")

    sumoBinary = "C:\Program Files (x86)/DLR/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe"
    sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "sim/sumo_config.sumo.cfg"]

    speed_error = []
    ntg_error = []

    for i in range(0,n):
        print(i)
        sumoBinary = "C:\Program Files (x86)/DLR/Sumo/bin/sumo.exe"
        sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "sim/sumo_config.sumo.cfg"]
        traci.start(sumoCmd) 
        while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
           traci.simulationStep()
           setVehType()

        traci.close()
        speed, ntg = Auswertung.auswerten()
        speed_error.append(speed)
        ntg_error.append(ntg)

    speed_mean_error = sum(speed_error)/len(speed_error)
    ntg_mean_error = sum(ntg_error)/len(ntg_error)    
    return speed_mean_error, ntg_mean_error
```

Comment: "in every itereation"  - what's the iterations context? maybe add the outer scope

Comment: I edited it. Essentially its just a loop, where the parameter in `xn` and `xb` get modified each iteration, and it runs till the error, which is returned by the `runSim()` call, is small enough. (Where the error is the difference between my simulation and some real data)

Comment: how is `runSim()` implemented? when you work with `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process` objects, you have to join them. If `runSim()` already joins them, your code doesn't run parallel.

Comment: post `runSim` definition and `e` value

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest @Aemyl I added `runSim`. `auswerten` just reads in some csv file to evaluate the simulation output. And `e` ist just a percentage treshold i want to reach, like 1%. SUMO is a tool for traffic simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) the following code would do:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=2)              # start worker processes

while True:
    # launching multiple evaluations asynchronously
    p1 = pool.apply_async(runSim, (xn[0],xn[1],25,na))
    p2 = pool.apply_async(runSim, (xb[0],xb[1],25,na))
    f_xn = p1.get()
    f_xb = p2.get()
    if f_xn < e:
        break
```